# Can Mail.app be configured to always load remote images from certain domains?

Tags: mail.app

I like how Gmail gives me the option to, for example, `Always display images from allsongs@n.npr.org`.

Is there a way to have Mail.app do the same? I can only find the global option for displaying remote images in HTML messages.

Answer (score 3):

#### Short answer

There is no specific option for this. But you can define a rule and run an applescript.

#### Solution

1. Save applescript below with any name and to any folder you want.
2. Go to `Mail app > Preferences > Rules` and click `Add Rule`. Give name **theRule** to your new role and select conditions that you want to display remote images. For your question this should be `From` > `allsongs@n.npr.org`.

   - You could also select `Sender is in my Address Book` to display remote images for all mails come from  your contacts.
3. Under `Perform the following actions:` section, select `Run Applescript` and choose the file you wrote at step 1.
4. Save the rule.

#### Applescript

```
--BEGINNING OF SCRIPT
using terms from application "Mail"
on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule
tell application "Mail"
activate
repeat with eachMessage in theMessages
open eachMessage
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Mail"
set loadButton to a reference to button 1 of UI element 1 of row 1 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of front window
if loadButton exists then click loadButton
end if
end tell
end repeat
end tell
end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
--END OF SCRIPT
```

Comment: This does not work in Mail 7.3 (OS X 10.9)