# Set "Load remote content in messages" per sender?

Tags: macos, applescript, mail.app, mail-rules

In the `Mail` setting (under Viewing) tab, there is a option `Load remote content in messages` which I **unchecked**, so for each email that contains remote content, I need to click the `Load remote content` button.

Is there anyway of a setting (probably not) or plugin that does this automatically for senders you would approve?

Comment: One possible way can be by setting up a rule which runs an apple script (if the senders is in a group) which somehow taps "load remote content"

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19811/can-mail-app-be-configured-to-always-load-remote-images-from-certain-domains

Answer (score 1):

In **macOS High Sierra**, I do the following to automate the clicking of the **Load Remote Content** *button* in **Mail**.

Using an **Automator** *Service* with setting **Service receives [no input] in [Mail]** and a **Run AppleScript** *action* replacing the default *code* with the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* and setting a *keyboard shortcut* in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** of **⇧⌃⌘L** this works for me, however in other versions of **macOS** the *example* **AppleScript** *code* may need to be adjusted to click the target *button*.

```applescript
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    tell application process "Mail" to ¬
        click button "Load Remote Content" of ¬
            group 1 of group 1 of scroll area 2 of ¬
            splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1
```

**Note:** I had to add **Mail** to **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility** for this to work.

---

Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted.

Comment: This isn't automatic, it's just a keyboard shortcut for the manual method.

Comment: This may not be an exact solution to the question, but it was helpful for what I wanted to do (load images via keyboard shortcut). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**The only (ugly) solution to date seems to be:**

```
tell application "System Events"
    click at {x, y}
end tell
```

— where *x* and *y* are coordinates of the mouse over the button to simulate a click (You can easily find these coordinates by doing a screenshot, i.e. cmd+shift+4)

**Note**: This will only work for the first message in a conversation since the button will be at the right place.

**Tip**: Although a dirty workaround, I accept this compromise as I make it more user-friendly by launching the script via a three-finger click through BTT.

Answer (score 0):

I believe user3439894 solution needs to be updated now to reflect the new button text:

```
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    tell application process "Mail" to ¬
        click button "Load Content Directly" of ¬
            group 1 of group 1 of scroll area 2 of ¬
            splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1
```