# How to open excel files attached to emails using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, mail.app, email, ms-office

My goal is to write a script that opens an attachment in excel when activated by a mail rule. It does not need any loops to go through multiple emails or attachments, just run once per email and then start again when the mail rule is next activated.

Basically, all I'm missing is a way to set a variable to the alias of the attachment and then open the file in excel. Unfortunately I am very inexperienced and do not know the syntax needed to do so. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Running an AppleScript when  a rule is at work will fix loading remote content on a sender by sender basis too. If someone answers this, consider https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317407/set-load-remote-content-in-messages-per-sender too.